# Oracle SQL Count or Sum in case query?

Tags: sql, oracle, count, sum, case

I've researched five different threads on StackOverflow, and I feel like I'm getting close but still no cigar.  My original table has several sections, and each section has several rows, and each row has several positions.  I want to be able to query a result that lists the section, row, position, how many positions are above that one in the row (position number lower) and how many positions are below that one in the row (position number greater).

Here's what I have:

```
SELECT section, 
       row, 
       position AS P, 
       SUM(case when position < P then 1 else 0 end) AS Above, 
       SUM(case when position > P then 1 else 0 end) AS Below 
FROM OriginalTable 
GROUP BY section, row, position 
ORDER BY section, row, position
```

The sum case is not recognizing P as the position and when I change P to a number, the sums are way off.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: P is an alias defined in your SELECT clause. You may not use it anywhere else in the same SELECT clause (for example, in the condition inside SUM or COUNT or anything else). This has NOTHING to do with COUNT vs SUM and everything to do with valid and invalid references to a column alias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is a correlated subquery getting the `count()` of lower/higher positions for a section and row.

```
SELECT ot1.section,
       ot1.row,
       ot1.position,
       (SELECT count(*)
               FROM originaltable ot2
               WHERE ot2.section = ot1.section
                     AND ot2.row = ot2.row
                     AND ot2.position > ot1.position) above,
       (SELECT count(*)
               FROM originaltable ot2
               WHERE ot2.section = ot1.section
                     AND ot2.row = ot2.row
                     AND ot2.position < ot1.position) below
      FROM originaltable ot1
      ORDER BY ot1.section,
               ot1.row,
               ot1.position;
```

Another one is using the windowed version of `count()`.

```
SELECT ot1.section,
       ot1.row,
       ot1.position,
       count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ot1.section,
                                   ot1.row
                      ORDER BY ot1.position
                      RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW
                                    AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) - 1 above
       count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ot1.section,
                                   ot1.row
                      ORDER BY ot1.position
                      RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                                    AND CURRENT ROW) - 1 below
      FROM originaltable ot1
      ORDER BY ot1.section,
               ot1.row,
               ot1.position;
```

Comment: Instead of using `CURRENT ROW` and subtracting 1, couldn't you use `BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING` and `BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING`?

Comment: In first query, both `above` and `below` has `<`. --- In second query, you flipped the meaning of `above` (position number lower) and `below` (position number greater).

Comment: @Andreas: True for the `<`, corrected that, thanks. For the aliases: I mean `above` is the number of rows "above" the row (ordered descending, if visualized in a result) and analog for `below`. At least that's how I got the OP. Might as well be the other way round though...

Comment: Wow, thanks @stickybit!  Both solutions worked, so it was a matter of speed.  Option 1 above took 15.5 seconds to run, option 2 clocked in at a blistering 0.00 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

I would just use `row_number()`:

```
SELECT section, row, position AS P, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY section, row ORDER BY position ASC) - 1 as Above,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY section, row ORDER BY position DESC) - 1 as Below
FROM OriginalTable
ORDER BY section, row, position;
```

If you have duplicates, then the problem is a bit trickier (although `GROUP BY` would address that).  You may want `DENSE_RANK()` rather than `ROW_NUMBER()`.

Comment: Thanks Gordon.  your solution worked as well, and was fast (0.015 seconds), but not as fast as @stickybit solution #2 above.  Great job and nice clean code.

Comment: @ToddK . . . They should be pretty much equivalent in performance.  Measuring elapsed times that are in milliseconds requires a lot of care -- taking into account things like server load, hot caches, and so on.